# how to call the value stored in the union

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I have value of `X = 140`, stored in union, how should I call the that value?
So that I can proceed to do conversion by calling that value of X,  from union, in the first stage.

`i = function_name (un.in)` This code is not the full code as it's complex calling functions with some arguments., but I understand until this code where it  read and get the X value  from the big data then, X value is stored in union. (my union code as below):

```
union {
        long int   in;
        byte by[LONGEST];
        double db;
    } un;  //union code
```

Comment: Either post the "complex code", or just access the member. Make sure your are not overwriting it with anything.

Comment: You don't "store values in a union", you store them in a specific member of that union. And you can just access that member to get the value.

Comment: Don't post your "complex code" - instead, create a [mcve] and include *that* in your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, when you say **calling** a value from a union, you mean **accessing** it?

If so, here is an example on how to do so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union
{
    long int   in;
    byte by[LONGEST];
    double db;
} un;  //union code

int main (void)
{
    union un myUnion = { 0 };

    myUnion.in = 10; // Storing in a union.

    printf("in value = %ld\n", myUnion.in); // Accessing union members.

    return 0;
}
```